# Как правильно работать с регулярными выражениями?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать правильное регулярное выражение, чтобы массив находил (`res[1]`) объект был только '`Выполни мою команду'` а не `'команду'`. массив `res[0]` Будет иметь только одно слово `'сэр'`, а не `'сэр, выполни мою команду'`

фраза для str может меняться. Самое главное, чтобы первое слово являлось первым объектом, а после 1 слова пойдут на 2 объект

Должно быть только 2 объекта.

Команда: Сэр

1 объект: Сэр

2 объект: выполни мою команду

[image: Консоль]

```
let str = 'Сэр, выполни мою команду';
let res = str.match(/^(?:.*)\s(.*)/i, '!' );
console.log(res)
```

Comment: 2 объекта - 2 группы захвата)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно проблемы с распознаванием русских букв в шаблоне \w.
Попробуйте ^(.+?)\s(.*)$

Comment: Не стоит размещать новый ответ, если вы можете отредактировать свой старый.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно выделить все слова:

```js
const s = 'сэр, выполни мою команду';

const r = s.match(/\p{L}+/ug);

console.log(r);
console.log(r[0], r.slice(1).join(' '));
```

Если в соответствии с ТЗ:

```js
const s = 'сэр, выполни мою команду';

const r = s.match(/(\p{L}+)\P{L}+(.*)/u);

console.log(r[1]);
console.log(r[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так (\w+)\s(.*)
в первой группе любое слово потом пробел  потом все остальное

Comment: получаю null 
`let str = 'Сэр выполни мою команду';
let res = str.match(/^(\w+)\s(.*)$/i);
console.log(res)
`